# Async await Node.js Unit Testing code using Chai and mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm quite new to node and express. And have been trying to write test code using mocha, chai. Here's the part of the source code.

**googleService.js:**

```
const axios = require('./axios');

exports.hitGoogle = async (requestUrl, payload) => {
  let response = {};
  await axios.post(`${requestUrl}`, payload)
    .then((resp) => {
      response = resp;
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
  return response;
};
```

**readGoogle.js**

```
const googleService = require('./googleService');

exports.execute = async (data) => {
  console.log(`data ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
  console.log(`Name ${data.name}`);
  console.log(`Salary ${data.salary}`);
  console.log(`Age ${data.age}`);
  const payload = { name: data.name, salary: data.salary, age: data.age };

  await googleService.hitGoogle('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/create', payload)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200 || response.status === 201) {
        console.log(response.status);
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  return true;
};
```

**And here is my unit test file:**

```
const readGoogle = require('./readGoogle');

const jmsPayload = { age: '23', name: 'test', salary: '123' };

describe('Google ', () => {
  it('POST: Google.', async () => {
     readGoogle.execute(jmsPayload).then((result) => {
     results = result;
    console.log(`Final Result : ${results.toString()}`);
  });
});
```

When I execute this test file, post is successful ,

```
hitGoogle url=http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/create
hitGoogle payload=[object Object]
{ status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
```

Input values passed from test class to readGoogle.js is also read inside that,

```
data {"age":"23","name":"test","salary":"123"}
Name test
Salary 123
Age 23

**But I am getting Promise as output.** 

**SO I have rendered the promised value to a normal string and getting 'true' as final output.**
```

Also,

- 1)Is this is the right way of testing the async-await module?

  2) Do we need to add anything else in this test code like Settimeout
  or beforeEach or afterEach blocks?

  3) Do we need to use Sinon for spying or adding a stub to 'payload'
  in googleService.js?

Can anyone help or suggest me the right path?

Tried async way for executing test cases one by one in order as below,

```
const readGoogle = require('./readGoogle');

const jmsPayload = { age: '23', name: 'test', salary: '123' };

const common = require('./common');
const chaiHttp = common.chaiHttp;
common.chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Google ', () => {
  common.mocha.before((done) => {
    // Wait for the server to start up
    setTimeout(() => {
      done();
    }, 1000);
  });

  it('POST: Google.', async () => {
    const result = readGoogle.execute(jmsPayload);
    console.log(`Final Result : ${result.toString()}`);
  });
  it('POST: Google.', async () => {
    const result = readGoogle.execute(jmsPayload);
    console.log(`Final Result : ${result.toString()}`);
    setTimeout(() => {
    }, 1000);
  });
  it('POST: Google.', async () => {
    const result = readGoogle.execute(jmsPayload);
    console.log(`Final Result : ${result.toString()}`);
  });
  it('POST: Google.', async () => {
    const result = readGoogle.execute(jmsPayload);
    console.log(`Final Result : ${result.toString()}`);
  });
  it('POST: Google.', async () => {
    const result = readGoogle.execute(jmsPayload);
    console.log(`Final Result : ${result.toString()}`);
  });
  it('POST: Google.', async () => {
    const result = readGoogle.execute(jmsPayload);
    console.log(`Final Result : ${result.toString()}`);
  });
  it('POST: Google.', async () => {
    const result = readGoogle.execute(jmsPayload);
    console.log(`Final Result : ${result.toString()}`);
  });
});
```

But then I am getting,

**Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves**

Thanks in advance

Comment: hello @user1660325 have you resolved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 2 following solutions:

1) **Callback** convention:

```
describe('Google ', () => {
    it('POST: Google.', (done) => {
        readGoogle.execute(jmsPayload).then((result) => {
            results = result;
            console.log(`Final Result : ${results.toString()}`);
            done();
        }).catch((e) => {
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

2) **async/await** convention

```
describe('Google ', () => {
  it('POST: Google.', async () => {
    const results = await readGoogle.execute(jmsPayload);
    console.log(`Final Result : ${results.toString()}`);
  });
});
```

Comment: Tran Nope its not working with chained async calls and i am getting Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called;

Comment: Have you try all of these above ways? If yes, you can follow this pattern.  it('should not timeout', (done) => {
}).timeout(60000);

Comment: Your async function is exceed 2000ms, so it throw a error. So extend timeout by set .timeout(60000) in each test case.

Comment: yes @Hay Tran , gave 60000 but then this code is giving same timeout error, common.mocha.before((done) => {
    // Wait for the server to start up
    setTimeout(() => {
      done();
    }, 2000);
  });

Comment: So try to increase to 600000

Comment: Increased to 600000 , but then  also Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

Comment: Is this timeout really needed if we are using asyc await tests? @Hay Tran

Comment: Yeap, because your before block is doing so late. So set up .timeout(60000) in your before block too.

Comment: Tran, across test suits, it is not working.  That is the problem I found. There is one more test called facebookTest.js executing before this googletest.ja and so I am getting this timeout error. I gave this inside sepeartely inside each test suit/file, but then also the same timeout issue.

Comment: beforeEach(() => {
    // common suite timeout that doesn't really need to be placed inside before block
    setTimeout(() => {
    }, 60000);
  });
  afterEach((done) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
    }, 120000);
    done();
  });

Comment: Please read my guide carefully. I said set timeoute for **it** and **before** scope not inside that function scope. Example: it("test 1", () => { //your test case }).timeout(60000);. Do you understand?

Comment: Have you resoled the problem yet?

Comment: Tran no did not follow this solution for timeout, did other workaround and fixed

Comment: Consider not using arrow functions for mocha methods. See this. https://mochajs.org/#arrow-functions . Also, you will probably want to use this.timeout(foo) to set mocha timeout after the arrow function change.